# mysql not finding result when fname and lname is searched, but when fname or lname is searched for single it returns a result

Tags: mysql

below is my php snippet please how do i make my search to return result when i search for john doe am using a single search box in my php form with fname and lname saved in different column in my database. i only recive result when only fname or lname is searched.

```
$search_string = " AND (fname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR lname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')";
```

Comment: Sounds like you want fulltext search.

Comment: Mihai, please how do i implement a full text search

Comment: Whats your mysql version?

Comment: i use mysql Server version: 5.5.32

Comment: You can use fulltext search only with myisam engine if mysql is < 5.6.Is your table myisam?

Comment: i use innoDB for the creation of my database

Comment: i tired the snippet with CONCAT  i got error massage request "Could not execute SQL query

Comment: Just upgrade mysql to latest version adn use fulltext search on innoDB,if it is an option.

Answer (score 1):

Please use MySQLi or PDO. mysql_* is deprecated and insecure.

I no longer use mysql_* so this syntax may be incorrect, but this *should* work:

```
$search = "Joe Bloggs";
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE %$search% OR lname LIKE %$search%";
```

Comment: i used it but it returned all the names in the database including the onces i did not searched for